# Ejabberd roster odbc

Tags: configuration, odbc, ejabberd

I am new to ejabberd and I have a problem with mod_roster_odbc.
I follow the instruction here :
http://www.planeterlang.org/en/planet/article/How_to_install_ejabberd_2.0.0_with_PostgreSQL_support/
In the ejabberd.cfg, I replace mod_roster with mod_roster_odbc and provide pgsql infomation ( the infomation is correct)
I download the schema of ejabberd for pgsql in : 
( I fixxed some error of the queries, some commas are missing. ) 
https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/tree/master/src/odbc

But the odbc roster not work.
When I create user using ejabberdctl , it say: User newuser@domain already registered at node ejabberd@localhost . 
in the pgsql database, nothing changes, no data inserted .

So, my final question is :  I have a database stored rosters users, rostergroups , ... How do I use the mod_roster_odbc.

Thank you very much
Update 1 :
When I try to subscribe ( add user to roster using XMPP client) , I can see the log :

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 2012-09-16 12:29:21 ===
E(<0.308.0>:ejabberd_odbc:405) : SQL transaction restarts exceeded
** Restarts: 10
** Last abort reason: []
** Stacktrace: [{ejabberd_odbc,sql_query_t,1},
                {mod_roster_odbc,'-process_subscription/6-fun-0-',8},
                {ejabberd_odbc,outer_transaction,3},
                {ejabberd_odbc,run_sql_cmd,4},
                {p1_fsm,handle_msg,10},
                {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]
** When State == {state,<0.309.0>,pgsql,30000,"mossi",1000,{0,{[],[]}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find out the problem due to Postgres version. I change Postgres from 9.0 to 8.4 and that works.
The problem because Postgres 9.0 doesn't handle multi lines query using "\".